# Customization of Spring ConversionFailedException error HTTP status

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, parameters, enums, http-status-codes

I have an enum class:

```
class enum Type {
   LOCAL, REMOTE
}
```

I have an API that accepts the enum as a GET parameter

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, location="item", params = "type")
public Item[] get(Type type) {
...
```

When a client calls the API with valid values, like `GET /item?type=LOCAL` or `GET /item?type=REMOTE` it works fine. If the client supplies invalid value for `type`, e.g. `GET /item?type=INVALID_TYPE`, then Spring generates `500 Internal Server Error`. I would like to turn it into `400 Bad Request` validation error, potentially adding useful information for the client. I prefer to reuse the built type converter since in works just fine, just want to change a type of error HTTP thrown with minimum changes.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I want to do the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 2):

I believe if you add the right exception to `@ControllerAdvice`, you can customize the response.  In this case, I found that `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException` was the one in question.

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
public void methodArgumentTypeMismatchException(final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.sendError(BAD_REQUEST.value());
}
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. But using ConversionFailedException instead did work.

Answer (score -1):

**Why is this happening?**

I would consider having a look at the example [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) about the @ControllerAdvice and/or @ExceptionHandler annotations.  The error you're experiencing is occurring because, I believe, Spring tries to construct a Type from the "INVALID_TYPE" string and gets an error when it cannot create a Type from it--because "INVALID_TYPE" is not one of the available values.

**What can I do about it?**

What you'll want to do is add a string constructor to your enum so it knows, more correctly how to create one of the enum objects, and then check the input to see if its valid.  If it is invalid, throw a custom exception.  Then, in your @ControllerAdvice, you can customize the HTTP status code of the response.

The exception will then be able to be handled with something like the following:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)  // 409
    @ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
    public void handleConflict() {
        // handle the exception response, if you need information about the
        // request, it should be able to be attached to the custom exception
    }
}
```

The enum would look something like this:

```
public enum Type{

    LOCAL("LOCAL"), 
    REMOTE("REMOTE"); 

    private String type;

    private Type(String type) {
        if(type.equals("LOCAL") || type.equals("REMOTE")) {
            this.type = type;
        } else {
            throw new MyCustomException();
        }
    }

    public String getType() {
        return url;
    }

}
```

Comment: 2 questions: 1) I don't think the type conversion happens in the controller. Does the ControllerAdvice still apply to exceptions thrown in the framework beforehand? 2) Since enums are required to have private constructors, is the "else" statement above reachable?

Comment: 1) the type conversion doesn't happen in the controller--it happens via a default enum converter within spring.  2) yes, if any other string value is passed in, it will throw the exception.  If null is passed, it won't hit the converter because it doesn't match the converter method signature.